# Using Hardhat to deploy smart contract to local Polygon node

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, ethers.js, hardhat

I have followed [this tutorial](https://dapp-world.com/smartbook/deploy-smart-contract-on-polygon-pos-using-hardhat-bhta) to learn how can I use HARDHAT to deploy a Smart Contract on a Polygon testnet (and it worked just fine).

Now I want to run some tests on my local Polygon blockchain instance which is running and working fine on my local computer (with 4 nodes). I know it works because I can operate over it via jsonRPC and gRPG, consulting balances, status, etc.

So, in my hardhat.config.js I have this settings:

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "matic",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
    },
    matic: {
      url: "http://localhost:10002"
    }
  },
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.0",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  },
  paths: {
    sources: "./contracts",
    tests: "./test",
    cache: "./cache",
    artifacts: "./artifacts"
  },
  mocha: {
    timeout: 20000
  }
}
```

I then compiled and tryed to deploy Hardhat's sample script:

```
$ npx hardhat compile
>Downloading compiler 0.8.0
>Compiled 2 Solidity files successfully



$ npx hardhat run scripts/sample-script.js --network matic

>ProviderError: the method eth_accounts does not exist/is not available
>    at HttpProvider.request (/home/edu/projects/test-hardhat->polygon/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:74:19)
>    at GanacheGasMultiplierProvider.request (/home/edu/projects/test-hardhat->polygon/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/gas-providers.ts:312:34)
```

It seems Hardhat is calling the method eth_accounts which does not exist in my Polygon-Edge local blockchain.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

good question...  Ran into your question while troubleshooting the same issue.  I'm running `polygon-edge server --dev...` and couldn't deploy smart contracts with hardhat or truffle.  An alternative is to use Remix IDE and your wallet to deploy via Injected Web3 per the project's [Does polygon-edge support smart contract? #411](https://github.com/0xPolygon/polygon-edge/discussions/411) discussion.

[Deploy & Run Transactions within the Remix IDE, with selected environment with deploying via transaction.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu1YT.png)

Once completed you'll be able to review and approve the transaction within your wallet which in turn deploys the contract via transaction.  Pause for a second and **be vigilant of scammers, fake remix IDE clones, or incidentally deploying this transaction to a live network using real funds!**  With that said: [how to import a network to Metamask](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043227612-How-to-add-a-custom-network-RPC) if you have yet to do so.  If you need an account with funds, what worked for me was importing into Metamask an account via private key for which I included premined currency.  To retrieve the private key I referred to my validator node's data folder contained the private key at `$data-dir/consensus/validator.key` file.

Regarding the actual error and web3js.. The error message is accurate.  If you revisit the polygon-edge docs referencing [JSON RPC Commands](https://edge-docs.polygon.technology/docs/get-started/json-rpc-commands) note eth_accounts method call is missing.  This is problematic for the underlying node modules relying on web3.eth.getAccounts() call setup for contract deployment, and in turn impacting truffle and hardhat.